# Git : 'Binary Files Differ.' How to solve this issue in gitHub?

Tags: java, git, encoding, github

I have been facing this issue since yesterday. I have made some changes in some of the files (.js and .java files).

Now when I try to commit these changes using UI tool of Git for windows(GitHub), I get this message 'Binary Files Differ.'. I have been working with these files successfully until now. I don't know how this problem has come up.

I searched net and found that may be GitHub is wrongly treating this file as Binary file due to mismatch of encoding. I checked the encoding of files that have this issue and found that they have the same UTF-8 encoding that other files which have no issue have.

I also read that I can force git to treat the file as text file by specifying it in the .gitattributes file. But I don't know the location of this .gitattributes file. But I don't like this solution because this issue is there in many files and I find this as kind of a hack. I would like to know the cause of this and solve it properly.

How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version (2.2.0.0 5d1b386):

See https://windows.github.com/release-notes.html

Comment: This link has become useless.